# Убрать из названия раздела /index.php

Tags: .htaccess

Убрать из названия раздела /index.php

Например страницу http://site.ru/razdel/index.php

Требуется редиректить на http://site.ru/razdel/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?razdel/?$ /razdel/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Только не забудьте включить `mod_rewrite` в PHP

Answer (score 0):

Если адрес по которому идет обращение заканчивается на index.php или index.html, то делаем переадресацию:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/index\.(php|html)$
RewriteRule .*  http://site.ru%1/ [R=301,L,QSA]
```